# intelij spring boot hot swap causes context reload

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, hotswap

I am using Intellij 2017.2 with Spring Boot 1.5.4

When I recompile my current class with ctr+shift+F9, instead of the IDE doing a bytecode hotswap, the spring container gets reloaded.

On top of that, after the reload my RestConroller no longer works

I have tried adding / removing from my pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

please advise

Comment: Works fine on my machine with disabled "spring-boot-devtools" dependency. Have you reimported project from maven tool window after disabling that dependency?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is a spring boot bug as of the new version, but I ended up disabling manually the hot reload via properties:

This is done by setting the following in your application.properties:

```
spring.devtools.restart.enabled=false
```

The official doc:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart-disable